# Parameter removed from the query string is shown in the browser the first time

Tags: asp.net, url

I'm working on `ASP.NET Web Forms` app. In a certain moment I have to navigate to another page from javascript using

```
window.location = '/Clients/Edit.aspx?ClientId=' + id;
```

which leads to a url like so - `http://localhost:5870/Clients/Edit.aspx?ClientId=1`. However this is a bit misleading because once I'm on the edit page I may chose to edit another client and the next time I do it using `Ajax` request so the `URL` always stays with the id of the first user. Instead of looking for a way to show always the correct id (the user don't need this info) I prefer to just remove it so it's not misleading at least. So in my edit page I have this code:

```
 protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   if(!IsPostBack)
   {
     System.Reflection.PropertyInfo isreadonly =
       typeof(System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection).GetProperty(
       "IsReadOnly", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance |  
        System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        // make collection editable
        isreadonly.SetValue(this.Request.QueryString, false, null);
        // remove
        this.Request.QueryString.Remove("ClientId");
   }
  }
}
```

Which is almost working. When the page is loaded for the first time I still get the `ClientId=..` in my URL but then it's cleaned. However I don't want to show it at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume you have this URL:
`http://localhost:5870/Clients/Edit.aspx?ClientId=1`

You can use this as a JS code:

```
<script>
    window.history.pushState('obj', '', '.');
</script>
```

**Output:** `http://localhost:5870/Clients/`

Or use this:

```
<script>
    window.history.pushState('obj', '', 'edit.aspx');
</script>
```

**Output:** `http://localhost:5870/Clients/edit.aspx`

Note: Consider that this changes aren't valid for process and are only for show, so you can't use them as a new QuesryString and if you try to get the QueryString's value you get the original QueryString from the original URL.

Comment: I would prefer some permanent solution, but not showing the info to the user is something at least. After all I remove the value after the first request. So if no better solution is proposed I'll accept yours.

Comment: I don't figure out your mean about "permanent solution" but it's a general rule that you can't change the real browser's URL without a refresh for security issues. but you can change what is displayed.
If you want to change the ID in codebehind so save the current ID in a variable or property instead of write it in URL and then read it from URL.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I'm not quite knowledgeable about this topic so I may indeed write some things that doesn't make much sense. By permanent I mean that in my code behind I remove the `ClientId` parameter from the query string thus I'm expecting to be removed from the URL even at the first page load. However as you pointed out, there may be other reasons for it being part of the URL (security one for instance) so maybe the best solution is to hide it  with JS and then delete it with the code from the question. Anyway, gonna accept your answer. Thanks.